# Как сделать TextView прокручиваемым

Tags: android, xml, textview

Задача такова: у `TextView` не должно быть высоты, если в нем нет текста. Если же в нем есть текст, то максимальная высота `TextView`- 5 строк. Если весь текст из `TextView` не умещается в 5 строк (Или в определенную высоту по `dp`)- необходимо сделать `TextView` прокручиваемым. Не могу понять, как это все реализовать (Все через `xml` разметку)

**UPD:**

У меня TextView внутри View, которая лежит внутри ListView. И когда я пытаюсь проскроллить TextView, скроллится ListView. Может можно как-то поменять приоритеты скролла?

Comment: `android:maxLines="5" android:layout_height="wrap_content"`?

Comment: Это поставить у `ScrollView`, или у `TextView`? Если у `TextView`, там не нужен никакой больше атрибут? Ну, чтобы он стал прокручиваемым

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В разметке:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/myText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="false"/>
```

В методе `onCreate:`

```
String sometext;
TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
    if (sometext == null) {
        myText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        myText.setText(sometext);
    }

    myText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

В итоге, если не будет текста, `TextView` не будет отображаться, и не будет занимать места, а если текст есть, то у него максимум 5 линий, если больше 5 линий то дальше он только лишь прокручивается.

Comment: Да, наверное сразу надо было написать: у меня TextView внутри View, которая лежит внутри ListView. И когда я пытаюсь проскроллить TextView, скроллится ListView. Может можно как-то поменять приоритеты скролла?

Comment: @McDaggen Мне кажется, здесь будет NPE, ведь myText == null, а вы вызываете у него метод...